# can I use the same ant build file for windows and unix

Tags: ant

I had ant build file for windows box and can I use the same build file for deploying on Unix also ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take all the file names and OS-dependent items and put them in properties files with the same keys. Use the `<condition>` task to load the correct properties file:

```
<target name="init-os">
    <condition property="os.windows">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="os.unix">
        <os family="unix"/>
    </condition>
</target>
<target name="init-windows-properties" depends="init-os" if="os.windows">
    <property file="windows.properties"/>
</target>
<target name="init-unix-properties" depends="init-os" if="os.unix">
    <property file="unix.properties"/>
</target>
<target name="init-properties" depends="init-windows-properties, init-unix-properties"/>
<target name="init-directories" depends="init-properties">
    <mkdir .../>
    <!-- More directories -->
</target>
<target name="init" depends="init-properties, init-directories"/>
```

Add more to the "init" target for the rest of the work you need to do.

Comment: Well.. what I understood is OS specific config items can be separated but what about the commands for creation and compiling etc do they differ or the same targets work on both platforms. I guess they should otherwise we must be having 2 ant scripts but we are nto having in this case. I never tried ant on UNIX.

Comment: That's the whole point of Ant.  Look at the manual and the list of tasks.  The `<javac>` task  compiles Java files, and does the job of looking up the compiler based on JAVA_HOME.  The `<jar>` task executes the `jar` command, probably by executing `jar`'s jar by hand without going out to the OS.  Ant does convert file separators to the platform's separator as needed; stick with forward slashes and don't worry.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, too understood after referring to the site.